# Where to mint tokens from

Tags: solidity, smart-contract-wallets, mint

I'm new to evms and smart contract, so after I've deployed my token and smart contract, where do I need to go to, to mint more tokens to add to the existing supply. By the way this is the link attached to show the code

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x3134210a6bdb55eed6e59905bc34928df6d74830#code

Answer (score 1):

The contract doesn't have a public mint function so you won't be able to mint more tokens than those minted during deployment.

The minted tokens were in the deployer address. You can transfer them to other addresses.

Comment: So can I edit the contract to add it because I have a mint function as internal inside the code, here's the code: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x3134210a6bdb55eed6e59905bc34928df6d74830#code#L1

Comment: @HamidullahiSalaudeen Contracts are immutable. You could edit the source and deploy a new contract.

Comment: Thank you so much. So would that mean that I'll have to create a new token or the new contract would replace the old contract on my existing token and if you could please point me to a tutorial link that would be great

Comment: @HamidullahiSalaudeen It will be a separate contract from the previous one. This course seems fine https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-py.